# I want to update an app but it asks for another Apple ID

Tags: ios-appstore

Yes, this is asked a lot, but most people suggest deleting the app and re-installing it with your own Apple ID. I can't do that, because I have made serious progress and I lose it all if I do that. You can't connect to the app through Game Center etc, so I can't transfer data that way either.

What can I do?

Comment: Unfortunately, the way iOS is structured, to update (reinstall) an app, you must do it with the ID that originally purchased it with.  There's no way around it.

Comment: You can try to contact the app developers to see if they can work out an account system

Answer (score 3):

You have but two choices...

1. Use the Apple ID & password that was originally used to download the app.
2. Delete the app & re-download it under your own Apple ID.

There is no 3.

Comment: 1- I don't have the password for that Apple ID. If I had, I wouldn't have this problem.

Comment: 2- If I do that, I'm going to lose all my progress - which I especially pointed out that I didn't want to lose.

Comment: OK, there is a 3. Don't update it. You cannot get round the fact that you don't actually own the app you're trying to update. It belongs to the Apple ID that originally authorised the install.

Comment: If you downloaded the app in iTunes from the correct account what would happen if you then sync to iTunes...? Same app, different accounts. Would it update? If so would it keep the data?

Comment: You'd need the purchaser's ID before it would even sync. After that, idk, might depend on how the app itself handles the data.